# Fraction manipulation and binomial coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

I am working through a proof and I do not understand why the following equation holds:

$$\frac{m(m-1)(m+1)}{6} = \binom{m + 1}{3}$$

relative to the following definition of the binomial: $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! \cdot (n - k)!} $$

What is the basic rule of fractions and multiplication justifying the first equality above?

Comment: What is the relationship between $(m+1)m(m-1)$ and $\frac{(m+1)!}{(m+1 -[3])!}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$${{m+1}\choose 3 }= \frac{(m+1)!}{3! (m-2)!}=\frac{(m+1)(m)(m-1) (m-2)!}{3!(m-2)!} =\frac{m(m-1)(m+1)}{6}$$

Second to third equality:

By definition , $$(m+1)! = (m+1)(m)(m-1)(m-2)\dots 2\cdot 1 \\ = (m+1)(m)(m-1) \big[ (m-2)(m-3) \dots 2\cdot 1\big] = (m+1)(m)(m-1) (m-2)!$$

Third to fourth equality:

I cancelled out the $(m-2)!$ from the numerator and denominator. This leaves $$\frac{(m+1)(m)(m-1)}{3!} $$ Now, $3!=6$.

Comment: I don't understand how you get from the second equality to the third and how you get from the third equality to the fourth.

Comment: @Freddy Do you, now?

Comment: I don't really know the cancelling out rule, but if I just accept it, then your explanation makes sense to me. :)

Comment: @Freddy Cancelling terms basically follows from the fact that a number divided by itself is $1$.